# Unknown Column in Where Clause Python

Tags: python, mysql, select, where-clause

> mycursor.execute("SELECT PK FROM customers WHERE name = %s" %
>   customer)

Customer is a string.

I am new at MySQL and i'm doing an app in python and i have a problem with WHERE clause. This code generates this error:

> Unknown column 'Tomas' in 'where clause'.

Tomas is the name i want to find in my database.

My database looks has atributes: PK, name, surname, age, contact and 3 instances which one of them is Tomas. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have the name compared as a string instead of another column which is what i think mysql is doing. Try this

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT PK FROM customers WHERE name = `%s`" % customer)
```

NOTE: The string formatter is enclosed in backticks.